# Was there a battle during which iblis was a Child and his parents got killed?

Tags: shaitan, battles

The user [owari](https://islam.stackexchange.com/users/584/owari) on [This Question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/why-does-iblees-or-satan-refuse-to-bow-when-the-command-is-to-angels) commented that Iblis was a child and its parents got killed in battle.

What battle is he talking about, What is this story?

Comment: Meanwhile, about your question's title, it was not really related to the question's content, since certainly Iblis has been once a child, too, like other jinns, they grow, if I'm not wrong. Feel free to roll back if you didn't like the edit. :)

Answer (score 1):

I searched for the Hadeeth I was referring there in the books now available to me with no success (*so as well deleted that comment you were referring to it*), but there were other Ahadeeth saying that he at the time of the battle was not a child and was rather the chief of the jinns; then Allah sent him with a group of Angels to battle with those wrongdoers of Jinns and etc. on the Earth and he won the battle and remained with the angels and became arrogant of what he had done and he was very strong at worshiping Allah, then you know the rest of story. Note that the Ahadeeth about these types of issues may sometimes conflict in a minority or majority of details, so we can most probably conclude that there had been "something", but we cannot know its details unless imam Mahdi will lighten up our minds.

Meanwhile, the battle I am addressing here is probably the battle that drew an end to the mischief of jinns (*apparently the offspring of Jann*) and probably creatures called Nassnass (نسناس) before the creation of our father Adam --peace be upon him, actually about seven thousands of years before him.

> وَإِذْ قَالَ رَ‌بُّكَ لِلْمَلَائِكَةِ إِنِّي جَاعِلٌ فِي الْأَرْ‌ضِ
>   خَلِيفَةً ۖ قَالُوا أَتَجْعَلُ فِيهَا مَن يُفْسِدُ فِيهَا وَيَسْفِكُ
>   الدِّمَاءَ وَنَحْنُ نُسَبِّحُ بِحَمْدِكَ وَنُقَدِّسُ لَكَ ۖ قَالَ
>   إِنِّي أَعْلَمُ مَا لَا تَعْلَمُونَ
>
> Behold, thy Lord said to the angels: "I will create a vicegerent on
>   earth." They said: "Wilt Thou place therein one who will make mischief
>   therein and shed blood?- whilst we do celebrate Thy praises and
>   glorify Thy holy (name)?" He said: "I know what ye know not."
>   [Al-Baara,30]

If you need more info regarding the mischief before Adam peace be upon him see the Shia commentaries on the verse mentioned above, among other references, like the book written by Allamah Majlesi named السماء و العالم.

Godspeed

Comment: So the comment is deleted because you don't have evidence to prove it. Well, I searched and didn't find such story related to the question and also about the creatures you are talking about isn't yet clear. The hadith you have mentioned where Allah say "I will create a vicegerent" which mean the ruler so that means the human is the only one who came to earth not these creatures.

Comment: @Murtaza I've seen the hadith, I'll find it and get back to you later

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should ask about the origin of the conversation this is very important, is it true hadith or just some story that no one knows its origin.

So if someone couldn't declare a true source of his story which would be true hadith or Quran
that would mean one of two things:

1. First it would be nothing and totally nonsense which in that case you simply ignore it
2. Other thing you would need to ask someone that has knowledge which it would be Islamic scientist or we can say Sheikh

That’s the rule always.

Now for your story this is totally nonsense and its origin is unknown
So as long it doesn't have a true origin you can simply ignore it because to me it seems like a fairy tale.

Comment: I also haven't heard in my life about this story but that user has commented in that question and saying he can provide details. I am waiting for him.

Comment: always ask for the origin, never take anything lightly not because someone said it or someone wrote it in a book or webpage it would be true, simply because anyone can write and claim, but for every claim there should be solid prove other than this it is nonsense

Comment: Then that user should come and prove this.